# Is there a way to periodically prerender Angular Universal routes?

Tags: angular, angular-universal

My goal is to periodically prerender Angular Universal every 10 minutes so the content will be updated.

The problem is, I only can do it manually and once

```
npx ng run app-name:prerender --no-guess-routes --routes-file routes.txt
npm run serve:ssr
```

Comment: No, its not a built in feature in Angular. You could achieve a similar effect using a CRON Job, Node.js script, or doing some magic in your CI/CD pipeline.

Comment: @jimmykurian by some magic I assume this is not the normal way, isn't it? I am having trouble with TTFB due to slow response from our API, right I hotfix this with prerender. Is there a better way to get dynamic content while also SSR?

Comment: I said "magic" previously because my devops knowledge when it comes to CI/CD is very broad and not deep. So I feel like you can do it that way, I just don't know the details to to tell you how to do so.

Comment: When it comes to second part of your question you can consider a few strategies. First, implement server-side caching for API responses to serve subsequent requests faster. Second, optimize the API itself through query optimization or load balancing. Third, use client-side techniques like lazy loading, skeleton screens, or service workers to improve perceived performance. You can also use a Content Delivery Network (CDN) to cache your SSR pages closer to the user. Experiment with these methods to find the best combination for your specific needs.

Comment: Prerender is only useful if you don't have NodeJS on your webserver. You need to setup SSR instead

Comment: What kind of infrastructure are you hosting it on ? cloud, baremetal... ?